# How to get Table data in a db column from other database

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 computers. 1st one running database map1 and 2nd one map2. Now I want to get table of membership in map1 database from map2 of 2nd computer including data. So how can I import data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first need to create dblink extension on map2 as

```
Create extension dblink
```

After that you can create link and get table by using something like

```
SELECT * FROM 
dblink('dbname=map1 port=5432 host=127.0.0.10 user=postgres password=123',
       'select id, name_col from membership' )
       AS membership_from_map1(id integer, name_col text)
```

Use credential of map1 for dbname, port, host etc. You also need to check first that map is configured for remote access.

Comment: without remote way i cant copy data ?

Comment: If you have physical access to the map1 you can create backup and restore on map2. Other way you can create table on the output of dblink query, which will create a local copy of remotely accessed table.

Comment: A foreign table would be a better choice today